Using PostgreSQL index for WHERE and ORDER BY columns
For the following query, in scenario where we have < 25 records for the contracts 1, 2, 3, this query performs extremely slow:
SELECT *
    FROM transactions AS t
    WHERE t.contract_id in (1, 2, 3)
    ORDER BY t.transaction_time desc
    LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

Explain plan is the following:
1) Index Scan using index_1 on transactions t  
2) Filter: (contract_id = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))

We tried both variants of the composite index:
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON transactions (contract_id, transaction_time desc);

AND
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON transactions (transaction_time desc, contract_id);

but explain plan still looks the same.
How should we create our indices for situation when number of records is less than LIMIT?

Please show the true plan for EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), including the row estimates and actuals.  Your stylized version doesn't include this.
